# field selection within mongodb query using dot notation

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongokit

I see a lot of similarly worded questions here, but none has solved my problem.

I have a document like this:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5006916af9cf0e7126000000'),'data': [{'count': 0,'alis':'statsministeren','avis':'Ekstrabladet'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'thorning','avis':'Ekstrabladet'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'socialdemokratiets formand','avis':'Ekstrabladet'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lars barfod','avis':'Ekstrabladet'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'formand for det konservative folkeparti','avis':'Ekstrabladet'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'s\xf8vndal','avis':'Ekstrabladet'}, {'count': 0,'alis': u"sf's formand",'avis':'Ekstrabladet'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'m\xf6ger','avis':'Ekstrabladet'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lars l\xf8kke','avis':'Ekstrabladet'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'l\xf8kke rasmussen','avis':'Ekstrabladet'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lederen af danmarks st\xf8rste parti','avis':'Ekstrabladet'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'Pia Kj\xe6rsgaard','avis':'Ekstrabladet'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'statsministeren','avis':'Information'}, {'count': 1,'alis':'thorning','avis':'Information'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'socialdemokratiets formand','avis':'Information'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lars barfod','avis':'Information'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'formand for det konservative folkeparti','avis':'Information'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'s\xf8vndal','avis':'Information'}, {'count': 0,'alis': u"sf's formand",'avis':'Information'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'m\xf6ger','avis':'Information'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lars l\xf8kke','avis':'Information'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'l\xf8kke rasmussen','avis':'Information'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lederen af danmarks st\xf8rste parti','avis':'Information'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'Pia Kj\xe6rsgaard','avis':'Information'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'statsministeren','avis':'Berlingske'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'thorning','avis':'Berlingske'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'socialdemokratiets formand','avis':'Berlingske'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lars barfod','avis':'Berlingske'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'formand for det konservative folkeparti','avis':'Berlingske'}, {'count': 1,'alis':'s\xf8vndal','avis':'Berlingske'}, {'count': 0,'alis': u"sf's formand",'avis':'Berlingske'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'m\xf6ger','avis':'Berlingske'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lars l\xf8kke','avis':'Berlingske'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'l\xf8kke rasmussen','avis':'Berlingske'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lederen af danmarks st\xf8rste parti','avis':'Berlingske'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'Pia Kj\xe6rsgaard','avis':'Berlingske'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'statsministeren','avis':'JP'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'thorning','avis':'JP'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'socialdemokratiets formand','avis':'JP'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lars barfod','avis':'JP'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'formand for det konservative folkeparti','avis':'JP'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'s\xf8vndal','avis':'JP'}, {'count': 0,'alis': u"sf's formand",'avis':'JP'}, {'count': 1,'alis':'m\xf6ger','avis':'JP'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lars l\xf8kke','avis':'JP'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'l\xf8kke rasmussen','avis':'JP'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lederen af danmarks st\xf8rste parti','avis':'JP'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'Pia Kj\xe6rsgaard','avis':'JP'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'statsministeren','avis':'BT'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'thorning','avis':'BT'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'socialdemokratiets formand','avis':'BT'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lars barfod','avis':'BT'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'formand for det konservative folkeparti','avis':'BT'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'s\xf8vndal','avis':'BT'}, {'count': 0,'alis': u"sf's formand",'avis':'BT'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'m\xf6ger','avis':'BT'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lars l\xf8kke','avis':'BT'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'l\xf8kke rasmussen','avis':'BT'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lederen af danmarks st\xf8rste parti','avis':'BT'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'Pia Kj\xe6rsgaard','avis':'BT'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'statsministeren','avis':'Politiken'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'thorning','avis':'Politiken'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'socialdemokratiets formand','avis':'Politiken'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lars barfod','avis':'Politiken'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'formand for det konservative folkeparti','avis':'Politiken'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'s\xf8vndal','avis':'Politiken'}, {'count': 0,'alis': u"sf's formand",'avis':'Politiken'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'m\xf6ger','avis':'Politiken'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lars l\xf8kke','avis':'Politiken'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'l\xf8kke rasmussen','avis':'Politiken'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'lederen af danmarks st\xf8rste parti','avis':'Politiken'}, {'count': 0,'alis':'Pia Kj\xe6rsgaard','avis':'Politiken'}],'time':'2012-07-18 12:35:22.241245'}
```

I.e.:

```
{_objectId : xxx, time: yyy, data :[ 72 similar dicts in this array ]}
```

I want to retrieve values from within one of the 72 dicts.

My first attempt was something along these lines:

```
db.observations.find({'data.avis':'Ekstrabladet', 'data.alis':'thorning'}, {'data.count':1})
```

That would retrieve 72 `count` dicts, when what I really wanted was the count value for the array which satisfies both `avis:ekstrabladet`and `alis:thorning` (only one array). But instead mongo returns the whole document.

I have foundt $elemMatch, but I get the same output.

```
db.observations.find({'data' : {$elemMatch: {'alis':'thorning','avis':'Ekstrabladet'}}},{'data.count':1})
```

I guess I could iterate over the complete document in python (this is for a flask app), but it doesn't seem very elegant.

So my question is: How do I reach inside a document and grab values from a nested document of arrarys?

Bonus: As I am new to all sorts of databases I only chose mongodb because it seemed very nice and flexible, and because I don't work with critcal data. But I have no need for scalability and could use e.g. sqlite instead. If you have strong opinions about me using the wrong tool for the job - then please abuse me.

Comment: if you frequently manipulate single sub document did you consider a different schema, maybe where each document is like your elements of the array plus the top level fields?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky well - yes/no. Yes I have thought about, no I am just muddeling along here. However: The structure represents information that is fetched at the same time, for that reason it makes more semantically sense for me like this. But I should probably look into a new schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You cannot return just the selected subdocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/mongodb-extract-only-the-selected-item-in-array?lq=1). You'll get all of them. So you'll have to filter on the client side.

`$elemMatch` is of the essence, though, otherwise you would not be matching avis and alis against the *same* array entry (having one each that matches either would suffice, AND vs OR in a way).

Comment: Damn... I will have to take your word (backed up by almost 60K karma) for it ;-)  

ps. When I run from my python app the exact same find query which works in the shell, the output is a `pymongo.cursor.Cursor object`- which I have no idea what to do with (so I don't know hot to filter on client side). - I'll most likelly figure it out. But puts it here also ;-)

Comment: just for any other newbies: the `Cursor`object is the whole query returned. If there is more than one document in the query, you have to loop though the object. something like {% for i in results %} print {{i}} {% endfor % }